# Configuration of Cognito Forms with MailChimp

Tags: cognito-forms, mailchimp

Is there any way to have the contact information to be automatically uploaded to our MailChimp account from all form submissions?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Although we do not have a way to directly send over information from Cognito Forms to Mail Chimp. You can use [Zapier](https://zapier.com) to have each entry submitted also send information into your Mail Chimp account. You can learn more about how Zapier can help send data to Mail Chimp and other useful programs, and how to activate the Cognito Forms Zap, check out our [Blog post](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/connect-your-cognito-forms-to-almost-anything-with-zapier) on the topic.